# Looking for recommendations for an engineering simulation software system

Tags: simulation, software

We just won an award to create a (very) large and complicated simulation for a robotic swarm operating in its environment. We need to simulate the environment, the external inputs, the robots' sensors and hardware, and their internal algorithms. Being able to display nice graphics of the whole scenario is important as is being able to take models written in a variety of languages such as C++.

Would anyone have experience with/recommendations for a platform for developing such a simulation. So far, I'm looking at MatLab/Simulink, but would be willing to consider other platforms such as the Dassault packages. We could roll our own from libraries such as TechSoft's Hoops 3D rendering STK, but an existing software platform would be ideal.